# Perl:Match a pattern and print next N lines K times

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file which is like this

```
count="4"
data1
data2
data3
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

I need to search for the string `count` and take its value (4) and print the next 3 lines count(4) times.

The output in the file should be

```
data1
data2
data3
data1
data2
data3
data1
data2
data3
data1
data2
data3
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

I tried this Perl code

```
while ( <FILE> ) {
    $n = 3
    if ( $_ =~ /count="4"/ ) {
        print FILE if ($n-- > 0) x 4;
    }
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

> But its not working.

This is because

```
if ($n-- > 0) x 4
```

does not do what you want. `x` repeats a value (i.e. you're doing `if 1111`), it does not redo a statement.

Try:

```
use strict; use warnings;
while (<FILE>) {
  if ( /count="(\d+)"/ ) {
    for ( 1..$1 ) {
      if ( defined ( my $l = <FILE> ) ) {
        print $l;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That will get you started.

In future, note:

- Instead of "its not working.", give the actual output (even if all you can say is "it prints nothing, and throws no errors")
- When something doesn't work, consider [the perl debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)
- Notice `use strict;` and `use warnings;` - [these will help you](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) [avoid mistakes](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).
- Learn about capturing from [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) and [$1 and other regular-expression-related variables perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: Nice explanation. Nice to see instructions to debug things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;

while (my $line = <DATA>){
    if ($line =~ /count="(\d+)"/ and $1){
        $count = $1;
        next;
    }
    if ($count){
        print $line;
        $count--;
    }
}
__DATA__
count="2"
a
b
c
d
count="1":
e
f
g
count="3"
h
i
j
k
l
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give file/input at `@data`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my @data = qw /count="4" data1-1 data2-1 data3-1 Data1 Data2 Data3/;
my $repeat_line = 3;
foreach (@data)
{
  if ( /count="(\d+)"/ ) {
    for ( 1..$1 ) {
      for my $no1 ( 1..$repeat_line ) {
    print $data[$no1],"\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
for my $no ($repeat_line..scalar(@data)) {
  if(defined $data[$no+1]){
    print $data[$no+1],"\n";
  }
}
```

output

```
data1-1
data2-1
data3-1
data1-1
data2-1
data3-1
data1-1
data2-1
data3-1
data1-1
data2-1
data3-1
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print m/count="(\d+)"/?$n=(<>.<>.<>)x$1:$_' file
#         ^     ^                ^            ^  ^^---- the current line.
#         |     |                |            |  '---- else
#         |     |                |            '---- repeated $1 times
#         |     |                '---- the three next lines (if any) stored in $n
#         |     '---- when this pattern succeeds,
#         '---- Print,
```